# Is possible to get web application full url from Spring service that is invoked by task?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I have service which is not invoked by user request, but by task. Now I need to send email from this task, and email contains link to my web application, how can I get full url of my application so that my email can link back to my web application?

Example of service:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Scheduled(cron="0 */10 * * * *")
    @Transactional
    public void myTask() throws IOException, ParseException
    {
        // Now I have to send email with my app url, but how can I get it here ?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it, since web application actually doesn't know its own domain name. It can only extract a domain name used to send a request from that request.

Therefore domain name of your application should be a part of configuration, and your task should obtain it from there.