# get application domain + port and path programmatically in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My website calls a rest service which is also on the same application. I don't want to change the domain of the rest address if it's hosted on a different domain name and/or port. I want to get the domain, port and application path programmatically.

If we are accessing the website like

http://example.com/article1

then I should get http://example.com

or if our address is like below

http://example.com:8080/ArticleSite/article1

then I want to get http://example.com:8080/ArticleSite

How can this be done?

I did look at the answers at

[What's the best way to get the current URL in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490821/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-current-url-in-spring-mvc)

but non are getting the application path.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to get the current URL in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490821/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-current-url-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: It does not look like any of those answers are getting the application path.

Answer (score 0):

Hope im not late for the party.

I had issue similar to yours, and i managed to solve first part of your question by using `ServletUriComponentsBuilder`.

I've been using it like this to get current server URL:

```java
ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().build().toUriString();
```

which would return http://localhost:8080 for me

EDIT: everything i wrote will not work, i'm working on a similar issue as OP, and this fix partially worked for me, after some digging i found this question, that has already been answered:

[Is possible to get web application full url from Spring service that is invoked by task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040209/is-possible-to-get-web-application-full-url-from-spring-service-that-is-invoked-by-task)

EDIT2: this guy also says it's not possible:
[How do I find base URL during Spring MVC startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567438/how-do-i-find-base-url-during-spring-mvc-startup)